# How to wrap monadic action in IO

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, reader-monad

I am trying to treat a `ReaderT X IO` monad as IO to achieve the following:

```hs
-- this is the monad I defined:
type Game = ReaderT State IO                                                                                                            

runGame :: State -> Game a -> IO a                                                                                                      
runGame state a = runReaderT a state                                                                                                    

readState :: Game State                                                                                                                 
readState = ask                                                                                                                         

-- some IO action, i.e. scheduling, looping, etc.                                                                                                                    
ioAction :: IO a -> IO ()
ioAction = undefined

-- this works as expected, but is rather ugly                                                                                                                                       
doStuffInGameMonad :: Game a -> Game ()                                                                                                 
doStuffInGameMonad gameAction = do                                                                                                      
  state <- readState                                                                                                               
  liftIO $ ioAction $ runGame state gameAction
```

`ioAction` for example is scheduling another IO action in intervals. Unwrapping the `Game` monad every time seems a bit cumbersome -- and feels wrong.

What I am trying to achieve instead is:

```hs
doStuffInGameMonad :: Game a -> Game ()                                                                                                 
doStuffInGameMonad gameAction = ioAction $ gameAction
```

My intuition tells me, this should be possible somehow, because my `Game` monad is aware of IO. Is there a way to implicitly convert/unlift the `Game` monad?

Please excuse if my terminology is not correct.

Comment: No, you cannot implicitly unlift. It is always explicit. There are libraries to help, but under the hood they do exactly what you did here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One abstraction you can use is the [`MonadUnliftIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-core-0.1.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Unlift.html#t:MonadUnliftIO) class from the [`unliftio-core`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-core-0.1.2.0) package. You can do it using [`withRunInIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-core-0.1.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Unlift.html#v:withRunInIO).

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Unlift (MonadUnliftIO(..))

doStuffInGameMonad :: MonadUnliftIO m => m a -> m ()
doStuffInGameMonad gameAction = withRunInIO (\run -> ioAction (run gameAction))
```

Another less polymorphic solution would be to use [`mapReaderT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:mapReaderT).

```
doStuffInGameMonad :: Game a -> Game ()
doStuffInGameMonad gameAction = mapReaderT ioAction gameAction
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I will go with `mapReaderT`.

What I learned once more: In Haskell when you can come up with the signature of the function your are looking for, you almost solved your problem.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to define the game actions as a type class:

```hs
class Monad m => GameMonad m where
  spawnCreature :: Position -> m Creature
  moveCreature :: Creature -> Direction -> m ()
```

Then, declare an instance of `GameMonad` for `ReaderT State IO` - implementing `spawnCreature` and `moveCreature` using ReaderT / IO actions; yes, that will likely imply `liftIO`'s, but only within said instance - the rest of your code will be able to call `spawnCreature` and `moveCreature` without complications, plus your functions' type signatures will indicate which capabilities the function has:

```hs
spawnTenCreatures :: GameMonad m => m ()
```

Here, the signature tells you that this function *only* carries out GameMonad operations - that it doesn't, say, connect to the internet, write to a database, or launch missiles :)

(In fact, if you want to find out more about this style, the technical term to google is "capabilities")

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually address the question to me. In particular, once I have my `ReaderT State IO` instance, how do I use this new infrastructure that you recommend to make the implementation of `doStuffInGameMonad` less cumbersome?

Comment: As far as I understand (from an OOP background), what you (@typedfern) suggest is information hiding by using a type class. In my case that is not interesting, because the `ioAction` I referred to, should NOT belong to the same context as the Game Monad.

Comment: @MarkusRother, you can create multiple monads for different purposes: say, MonadGameState, MonadNetwork, etc; then, if you have a function that both changes the game state and accesses the network, you set two constraints: ```myFunction :: (MonadGameState m, MonadNetwork m) => m ()```. You can place the ioAction in question within whatever monad is appropriate, having your different effects grouped into different classes.